# How to convert String(Example: 2/May/19, 24/4/19, 2019/4/20) to Date in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to change Data text from my old database. It was different format like 2/May/19, 24/4/19, 2019/4/20. 
Could I convert all of them be like this format 'YYYY-MM-DD'?. Could I use PostgreSQL command to select them and update new one? Thank you for your help.

[image: My image data]

Answer (score 0):

Convert a date formatted **string** to a **DATE** data type.
You can try this

```
TO_DATE(string [, format ])
```

For Example:

```
TO_DATE('2007-07-04 13:39:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

You can follow the [link](https://www.enterprisedb.com/edb-docs/d/edb-postgres-advanced-server/user-guides/database-compatibility-for-oracle-developers-guide/9.4/Database_Compatibility_for_Oracle_Developers_Guide.1.120.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_char`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_char/) to extract dates from your strings, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  TO_DATE('2019-05-02 10:42:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
  TO_DATE('2019-05-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
  TO_DATE('2/May/19', 'DD/Mon/YY'),
  TO_DATE('2/5/19', 'DD/MM/YY'),
  TO_DATE('2019/5/19', 'YYYY/MM/DD');

  to_date   |  to_date   |  to_date   |  to_date   |  to_date   
------------+------------+------------+------------+------------
 2019-05-02 | 2019-05-02 | 2019-05-02 | 2019-05-02 | 2019-05-19
(1 Zeile)
```